# IDEA 2019.3 running very slow

Tags: scala, performance, intellij-idea

i have a plenty powerful machine, but IDEA is very slow. I'm using for scala and nothing more, i'm turned off every plugin, even git but it still thinks so long. Sometimes it frezees up to 30-60 seconds after typing 1 letter. It using not so much of RAM, maybe 2-4 GB's, use 1 or 2 threads, never seen more than that. Compiling only standalone sbt, without IDEA.
I'm running it on the machine:
 `dual x5670/142GB RAM/RAID-1 1TB HDD's`

Current version of IDEA/JVM:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-193.5233.102, built on November 28, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b520.11 amd64
```

Options:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
```

Also i'm using an x2go connection to a server via dedicated 100megabits ethernet, my terminal is `i5-2400/8GB RAM/debian-mate`, connection set to `adaptive/nosound/quality3`. Ping to server about 50ms's.

Comment: What's JVM used by IntelliJ and JVM options? You can check them in Help/About and  Help/Edit custom VM options.

Comment: As an option, you can download and attach the [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) to see what is happening under the hood. It can work in a wall clock, allocation, and event (CPU cycles, instructions, cache misses, etc,) modes and build interactive flame graphs like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/master/demo/SwingSet2.svg?sanitize=true) for all stack frames: Java, C++, kernel, etc.